# Functions may not be defined within control directives other mixins

Tags: node.js, gulp, mixins, compass

I have a node project and when i start the command line npm install, i have this error :

Message:
    node_modules\compass-mixins\lib\compass\functions_lists.scss
Error: Functions may not be defined within control directives or other mixins.
        on line 81 of node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/compass/functions/_lists.scss

> > @function compact($vars...) {

On my last project, with the same package.json i don't have any error.
Have you a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: One solution could be: `rm -rf node_modules; npm i`

Comment: I have the same error. Another solution ?

Comment: Upgrade nodejs version maybe?

Comment: I have already the last version

Comment: Last version is not stable. Try the v4.

Comment: Doesn't work, idea ?

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass
rm -rf node_modules
npm i

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Run `npm install node-sass@3.4.2`.
2. Add `"node-sass": "3.4.2"` into your `package.json` and then run `npm install`.